# How to handle JPA function exception

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

When I am calling save() of JPA it is giving exception of ConstraintViolation exception but it is inside nested exception.

First one is **IllegalStateException**, then **NestedServletException**, **DataIntegrotyViolationException**, **ConstraintViolationException**, **SQLServerException**
There

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'uk_urmapping_uname_role'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.employee_role_mapping'. The duplicate key value is (wxy ., ABC).
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1547) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:548) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
```

In CustomExceptionHandler class I added

```
@ExceptionHandler({ GenericJDBCException.class, SQLException.class, DuplicateKeyException.class,
        ConstraintViolationException.class, JDBCException.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> processSqlExceptions(SQLException e, WebRequest request) {
    logger.error("SQL Error : ", e);
    logger.warn("SQL Error : ", e);
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("600", e.getMessage(), tracer.currentSpan().context().spanIdString());
    return handleExceptionInternal(e, error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

I tried to handle some exception, still it is not able to handle exception.

Comment: You should validate the data before going to the database and return a meaningful message on validation error.

Comment: Have you tried by adding SQLServerException in ExceptionHandler?

Answer (score 0):

It is a `DataIntegrityViolationException` so you should have it added in the handler.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `hibernate` then it throws it's own version of `ConstraintViolationException`.

So make sure you handle `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` instead of `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` (or both).